# Continuity at $x=0$ of this function

Tags: functional-analysis, limits, proof-verification, continuity

Not a hard exercise:$$f(x)=\frac{1}{x^3}\cdot \int_{-x}^x \sin(4t^2) \, \text{d}t \quad \text{where} \space x\ne 0\:$$
$$f(x)=5\:;\:x=0\:$$

Checking it's continuity at $x=0$ by using L'Hospital's rule and Newton-Leibniz axiom:

$$\begin{align} \lim _{x\to 0}\frac{1}{x^3}\cdot \int_{-x}^x \sin(4t^2) \, \text{d}t & =\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{2\sin(4x^2)}{3x^2} \\[10pt]
& =\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{2\sin(4x^2)}{8x^2}\frac{8x^2}{3x^2} \\[10pt]
& =\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin(4x^2)}{4x^2}\frac{8x^2}{3x^2} \\[10pt]
& =\frac{8}{3}\end{align} $$

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Is it correct ?

Comment: @graydad : Why do you consider it important to write f\left(x\right) instead of f(x)?  I think the former may mislead newbies into thinking those are necessary even in contexts where the default delimiter size is appropriate.  But you went to some trouble to change multiple instances of things like f(x) to f\left(x\right). ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Strange, but I dont see where did I write f\left(x\right) instead of f(x).

Comment: I don't see an error. apart from a typo in line 2...

Comment: Fixed it, thanks.

Comment: @MichaelHardy Ah, that was unintentional. I saw the question had been edited while I was editing (what you changed). So I copied my current edit (which had the original f\left(x\right) syntax from OP leftover) and pasted that when I made my edit. My apologies.

Answer (score 0):

In the way it is written here, you have made a minor mistake. I recommend you to pass from the first line to the third line directly and omit the x^2s.

Comment: I dont see any mistake, can you write it ?

Comment: It' s fixed now.